# Why won't my buttons align together?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm making a program and for some reason my buttons aren't aligning correctly. I tried making a codepen, but whenever I made it, it didn't look the same as mine does on my webpage. I'm hoping its just something little that my eyes missed with the styles, I'm using bootstrap and just want everything to be aligned nicely on one line.

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Person Summary</h3>

      <div style="float: left;">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-margin">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-margin">Edit</button>
      </div>

      <div style="float: right;">
        <div class="onoffswitch">
          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
          <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
```

and here's the css, most of it is for the onoffswitch:

```css
.panel-heading {
  background-color: #165284;
}

.panel-heading h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: normal;
  width: 75%;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
}

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "Days";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #84161B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "Hours";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #84161B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

Here's a picture of what it currently looks like 
[image]

Comment: How are they not aligned? Do you want the `0 hours` to also be aligned?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want `Save` and `Edit` to appear to the right of 'Person Summary' instead of below it?

Comment: @alexanderbird correct

Comment: @PhilipCorneliusGlover yes, everything should be on the same line, and the `"0 hours"` is actually a checkbox formatted as a switch

Comment: I would suggest adding `display: block;` to your `.panel-heading {...}` CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="panel-heading clearfix">
      <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Person Summary</h3>

  <div class="btns-container pull-right">
      <div style="display:inline-block">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-margin">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-margin">Edit</button>
      </div>
    <div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
        <div class="onoffswitch">
          <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
          <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
            <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.panel-heading {
  background-color: #165284;
}

.panel-heading h3 {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: normal;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: white;
}

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "Days";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #84161B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "Hours";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #84161B;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}
```

wrap the buttons in a div and add class pull-right. and also add clearfix to the panel-heading

and also remove width to the h3 element

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS at the begging from

```
.panel-heading {
  background-color: #165284;
}
```

To this

```
.panel-heading  {
  background-color: #165284;
  display: block;
}
```